# What else is required to get this chart rendered?

Tags: symfony, user-experience

With Symfony UX, in order to assure that a custom chart could be rendered, I started with the [sample from documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-chartjs/current/index.html#installation). The rendered page is effectively blank. In the browser's console is this string:

```
<canvas data-controller="symfony--ux-chartjs--chart" data-symfony--ux-chartjs--chart-view-value="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;line&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;labels&quot;:[&quot;January&quot;,&quot;February&quot;,&quot;March&quot;,&quot;April&quot;,&quot;May&quot;,&quot;June&quot;,&quot;July&quot;],&quot;datasets&quot;:[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;My First dataset&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;rgb(255, 99, 132)&quot;,&quot;borderColor&quot;:&quot;rgb(255, 99, 132)&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[0,10,5,2,20,30,45]}]},&quot;options&quot;:{&quot;scales&quot;:{&quot;y&quot;:{&quot;suggestedMin&quot;:0,&quot;suggestedMax&quot;:10}}}}"></canvas>
```

I interpreted that string to mean that the rendering process got as far as `chart.js`. But what later step(s) could prevent the chart from being fully rendered? Earlier step(s)?

`assets\controllers.json`:

```
{
    "controllers": {
        "@symfony/ux-chartjs": {
            "chart": {
                "enabled": true,
                "fetch": "eager"
            }
        }
    },
    "entrypoints": []
}
```

`package.json` includes:

```
    "devDependencies": {
    ...
        "@symfony/ux-chartjs": "file:vendor/symfony/ux-chartjs/assets",
    ...
        "chart.js": "^3.4.1",
    ...
}
```

`../node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js`: `Chart.js v3.9.1`

Comment: It appears to be browser dependent - Chrome OK, Firefox not. On Windows platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully(?), there are no discussions of Chart.js at the Mozilla forums. Applying the principle of pressing buttons until things change, I learned that the ad blocker I use was preventing the chart from being rendered. **W**hy **T**hat, **F**irefox?